# Нахождение функции (кривой) отклика камеры

Tags: java, алгоритм, изображения

Интересует алгоритм нахождения кривой отклика фото камеры из набора нескольких изображений одной сцены и с разной экспозицией. Может кто-нибудь на пальцах объяснить или дать ссылку на русскоязычный ресурс?

Есть экспозиция - выдержка. Матрица или пленка фотокамеры поддается закону отражающему ее реакцию на яркость снимаемой сцены, т.е. если яркость участка снимаемой сцены такая-то, экспозиция такая-то, то фотоэлемент так-то прореагирует. Вот этот закон и описывается кривой отклика камеры, с его помощью можно предсказать какая должна быть освещенность пикселя для такой-то выдержки. Точно видел описание, что нахождение этого закона поддается определенному алгоритму (или даже формуле), но не видел оную. Применяется в различных методах обработки изображений, моделировании сцен и т.п..

Comment: нехватает тега - учебное задание)))

Comment: к сожалению нет, я был бы рад если бы мне дали такое задание, мог бы преподавателя спросить.

Comment: @raskilas, опишите задачу подробней

Comment: добавил описания, но это и есть моя конкретная задача

Answer (score 4):

Примерно это можно реализовать так:

1. Берем фотографию (битмап) и рассчитываем среднюю интенсивность изображения. То есть фактически берем пиксель, раскладываем его на 3 компонента RGB и по каждой компоненте рассчитываем интенсивность и т.д. циклом по всем пикселям. В итоге получаем 3 цифры - средняя интенсивность по каждому RGB каналу.
2. Далее берем значение экспозиции, которое рассчитывается как: `[длительность выдержки]*[диаметр диафрагмы]`, что-то типа: `1/400*1/16`
3. В итоге по каждому из RGB каналов у нас будет 1 точка на графике.
4. Берем следующую фотографию - получаем еще 1 точку - ну и т.д. пока не получится осмысленный график.

P.S. Только надо будет какую-то вносить поправку на ISO чувствительность камеры.

Comment: Вопрос по первому пункту. Интенсивность рассчитывается по формуле Y = 0.2125·R + 0.7154·G + 0.0721·B т.е. выйдет одно число на пиксель (3 канала) => количество интенсивностей на одно изображение равное количеству пикселей, вы предлагаете находить среднеарифметическую?

Comment: @Raskilas это очень интересный вопрос :) По идее конечно же надо брать среднеарифместическое, но - если считать, что пиксели расположенные в центре изображения как бы главнее - поскольку когда мы смотрим на изображение то в первую очередь обращаем внимание на центр кадра, то можно придумать некую весовую функцию типа эллипса. Скажем в центре изображения вес=1, а по краям чутка меньше.

Answer (score 2):

Вот [алгоритм](http://www.optoresolver.com/help/calculations/Optoelectronic%20Transfer%20Function.htm), на английском правда. Он?

Comment: Нет, я так понял что это расчет и прогнозирование передаточной характеристики (функции) светодиода.